# problem in select change event

Tags: jquery, drupal-6

I have a drop down list on a page. I implement change event on this drop down list using jquery and its work fine. here is my jquery code.

```
drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(
        $('.$form['title']['select'].').change(function () {
    var str = "";
        var date = "";
    $("'.$form['title']['select'].' option:selected").each(function () {
      str += $(this).text() + " ";
      date += this.value + " ";
            $("#edit-titletext").val(str);
            $("#edit-datetext").val(date);

    });

  })
    )
  .change();', 'inline', 'header');
```

Where title is the field name and select is its type. titletext and datetext are field names of textboxes. My code was working fine up to this.

But on the same a page i place a block which has another drop down list. Now when i change a value in the block's dropdown lis, that jquery code also executed for this change event. Now the change event executed on both drop down lists. 
And i want it to execute only on the first drop down list which has a name 'title'.

Any one who can solve my problem...

**Edit:** The `$form` object

```
$form = array();
$form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select a forum'),
    '#page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    '#page arguments' => array('test_select'),
    '#access callback' => TRUE,
    '#options' => $options
);
```

Comment: Could you add the PHP `$form` object you are using so that a correct selector can be determined?

Comment: Here is my form code.<code>$form = array();
$form['title'] = array(
 '#type' => 'select',
 '#title' => t('Select a forum'),
 '#page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 '#page arguments' => array('test_select'),
 '#access callback' => TRUE,
 '#options' => $options,
 
);</code>

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event is bound to all elements that match the selector being produced by whatever `$form['title']['select']` is equating to.

So, if `$form['title']['select'] = .mySelect` then the resultant declaration would be:

```
$('.mySelect').change(function() {...});
```

so will be bind the change function() to any element that matches the CSS class `.mySelect`.

So if I assume your `$form` object is called `myForm`, then the following should bind the event to only the CSS selector `select[name="title"]`.

```
$('select[name="'.$form['myForm']['#title'].'"]').change(function () {...});
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure which part you don't understand. Your question was incomplete so I was including enough information for you to be able to work it out for yourself. That aside, you should just need to change the jQuery selectors to:

```
$('select[name="title"]').change(...
```

and

```
$('select[name="title"] option:selected').each(...
```

since already know the name of the `<select>` so why not just substitute it?

Also, I think you might find the [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) documentation useful.

Comment: Your code is so complex. Please add your code in my code so that i can use it. And also tell me what attributes should I add to the drop down list? Thanks